# Maximum number of categories in a Basic Bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to know if there's a limit, in basic bar chart, of the number of categories (the number of bars).

The question is : How many categories, a basic bar chart, can support ?

I already searched in the official doc but I didn't found anything about this.

Any clue will be welcome.

Comment: You can put in as many as you want. Performance may suffer as this is rendered client side. How many are you thinking you need? There could be a maximum usefulness amount as well.

Comment: ^ Yes. Maximum useful number of categories and maximum possible categories are very different things. You will find the limit of useful categories quickly. The limit of possible categories relies on the client's device resources.

Comment: Common sense answer is, if you're worrying about whether the chart can handle all of your categories, there's a really good chance you're approaching your data visualization wrong.

Comment: In fact I'm worrying about the display, can I force the display of all the categories ?

Comment: You can force that by using [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) and return ticks with interval 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Number of categories per axis is limited to 1000.**

At 1001 categories, the chart breaks.

See this fiddle for practical test (1000 vs 1001 categories): https://jsfiddle.net/3r2psy8u/4/

html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 10px auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="min-width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

js

```
var thousandCategories = [];
var thousandValues = [];

for(var x = 1; x < 1001; x++) {
      thousandCategories.push('category ' + x);
      thousandValues.push(['category ' + x, x]);
}

var thousandCategoriesPlusOne = thousandCategories.concat(['category 1001'])
var thousandValuesPlusOne = thousandValues.concat([['category 1001', 1001]])

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
                zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: '1000 categories'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: thousandCategories
    },
    series: [{
        name: '1000 categories',
        data: thousandValues
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: '1000 categories plus one'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: thousandCategoriesPlusOne
    },
    series: [{
        name: '1001 categories',
        data: thousandValuesPlusOne
    }]
});
```